# clone Git Repository

Tags: git, ansible, bitbucket

I wrote an ansible playbook which creates a new BitBucket repository.
Now I want to configure the repository according to the instructions shown under the repository source in BitBucket:

> You have an empty repository To get started you will need to run these
>   commands in your terminal. New to Git? Learn the basic Git commands
>   Working with your repository My code is ready to be pushed If you
>   already have code ready to be pushed to this repository then run this
>   in your terminal.

```
cd existing-project
git init
git add --all
git commit -m "Initial Commit"
git remote add origin http://xxxxxxx/scm/project/my-repo.git
git push -u origin master
My code is already tracked by Git
If your code is already tracked by Git then set this repository as your "origin" to push to.**

All done with the commands?
Refresh
```

Can I do this with the Git Module? Or how can I run those commands in ansible?
I only managed to clone the repo with the Git Module.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the answer by @Dan Farrell [Ansible Git](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/git_module.html) doesn't seems to allow push.

As an initial approach you can try something like:

```
- name: Git push.
  tasks:
    - name: Set git origin
      shell: "git remote set-url origin https://gitUserName:gitPassword@yourHost.com/storage/repo.git"

    - name: Push to origin.
      shell: "git push origin yourBranch"
```

Comment: Thank you very much.I got it to work with a small script of git commands

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/git_module.html seemse to support pulling, but I don't see any way to *push* with that module.

If I recall correctly, the `git` module for ansible simply wraps the `git` executable, so it should be relatively easy to write your own `shell` or `command` tasks to execute the git commands you want.

You'd probably want to use the `copy` module with the `content` setting to create a new file (git does not allow "empty" commits as it only tracks changes, and thus cannot commit without changes), and then run the `git add` and `git commit` steps conditionally on the file changing.

It's not in my experience a common practice to create git repos and manage their contents with Ansible.  I wonder at the utility of it ( you'd assumedly want to check the ansible itself into a repo to track changes to the ansible, so you end up doing manual git actions anyway.)  But certainly possible.

Comment: Thanks Dan for your input. I got it to work exactly the way you said,